# 2002 VW Jetta Wagon 2.0L - Gear shift stuck in park (automatic)

Tags: vw, transmission, automatic-transmission, shifting

This problem was intermittent until now.

Before the issue happened, the shifter would click whenever I put my foot on the brake, a light on the shift column will turn off, and I would hear a click indicating me that the gear shifter was no longer locked, and I can move it in other gears.

Now, the light still goes off as normal, but there is no click, and the gear shift does not move.

What could the issue be? What's causing the shifting column to not release my shifter?

Comment: A switch / relay that is no longer operating once you use the brake - the brake switch energises the wire to the lights and, either the same or a different wire will also send a signal / feed to the shifter interlock to let it release. So, check the brake switch, the wire and the relay /switch at the shifter.

Answer (score 1):

You should first check if you have any codes stored in your ecu. This can be related to an error in G68 or shift lock solenoid may be broken. You may have [a code](http://wiki.ross-tech.com/wiki/index.php/01236) which would make diagnosis much easier! For your car you should be able to use VCDS Lite and a 3rd party cable costs $15 or less! It is a good investment!

If you don't hear the click. It means your shift lock solenoid may be broken or does not receive power. Apparently there has been some VW models which missed some washers in EU which caused this problem often and got replaced. I am not sure if that applies to you. But you should be able to reach the solenoid easily to check it. [See this](http://forums.vwvortex.com/showthread.php?2292493)